# I am trying to insert json data into a snowflake table but can't access nested rows of more than 1 level

Tags: amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

The json

```
{
    "payload": {
        "orders": [
            {
                "orderDetails": {
                    "billToParty": {
                        "partyId": "X"
                    },
                    "purchaseOrderDate": "X",
                    "deliveryWindow": "X",
                    "purchaseOrderStateChangedDate": "X",
                    "sellingParty": {
                        "partyId": "X"
                    },
                    "purchaseOrderType": "RegularOrder",
                    "paymentMethod": "Invoice",
                    "buyingParty": {
                        "partyId": "X"
                    },
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "orderedQuantity": {
                                "amount": 14,
                                "unitOfMeasure": "Cases",
                                "unitSize": 1
                            },
                            "netCost": {
                                "amount": "X",
                                "currencyCode": "USD"
                            },
                            "itemSequenceNumber": "1",
                            "amazonProductIdentifier": "X",
                            "vendorProductIdentifier": "X",
                            "isBackOrderAllowed": true,
                            "listPrice": {
                                "amount": "X",
                                "currencyCode": "USD"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Now I am able to get all the party Id rows by using a query like

```
SELECT t.value:orderDetails:buyingParty:partyId from table(flatten(input => parse_json(select parse_json($1:payload:orders) from @avc_test_stage/test.json)))t;
```

but how can I do something like this in one single query as I want to insert all the data into a table eventually.

```
SELECT t.value:orderDetails:items:amazonProductIdentifier, t.value:orderDetails:buyingParty:partyId  from table(flatten(input => parse_json(select parse_json($1:payload:orders) from @avc_test_stage/test.json)))t;
```

Currently I am getting null for items:amazonProductIdentifier as these are in a row inside a row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`items` is an array, so you need to flatten it out, as well.  So, leveraging a CTE to define your example as:

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT parse_json('{
    "payload": {
        "orders": [
            {
                "orderDetails": {
                    "billToParty": {
                        "partyId": "X"
                    },
                    "purchaseOrderDate": "X",
                    "deliveryWindow": "X",
                    "purchaseOrderStateChangedDate": "X",
                    "sellingParty": {
                        "partyId": "X"
                    },
                    "purchaseOrderType": "RegularOrder",
                    "paymentMethod": "Invoice",
                    "buyingParty": {
                        "partyId": "X"
                    },
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "orderedQuantity": {
                                "amount": 14,
                                "unitOfMeasure": "Cases",
                                "unitSize": 1
                            },
                            "netCost": {
                                "amount": "X",
                                "currencyCode": "USD"
                            },
                            "itemSequenceNumber": "1",
                            "amazonProductIdentifier": "X",
                            "vendorProductIdentifier": "X",
                            "isBackOrderAllowed": true,
                            "listPrice": {
                                "amount": "X",
                                "currencyCode": "USD"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}') as var)
```

Your select portion for just the amazonProductIdentifier would be part of the 2nd lateral flatten like this:

```
SELECT z.value:amazonProductIdentifier::varchar
FROM x,
LATERAL FLATTEN(input=>x.var:payload:orders) y,
LATERAL FLATTEN(input=>y.value:orderDetails:items) z;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What if I want to calculate the sum of all amounts in the items array?

Comment: I would flatten out your data in a CTE and then you can execute ordinary aggregates in SQL as you normally would against that CTE.